# Dimension of a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathcal{F}$, $\dim V = n$, and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. The set $\mathcal{B}_T$ is defined by
$$
\mathcal{B}_T = \{S\in\mathcal{L}(V)\colon TS = 0\}.
$$
Then $\mathcal{B}_T$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$, but what is its dimension? I have found that it can be $0$, $n$ and $n^2$, but are there any other possibilities?

Comment: The fact that $TS=0$ means exactly that the image of $S$ is included in the kernel of $T$. So actually $S$ is a linear function $V\to \ker(T)$. What can you say about the dimension of the space of such functions?

Comment: Does this means that $\mathcal{B}_T$ is just $\mathcal{L}(V,\mathrm{ker}(T))$, and therefore $\dim \mathcal{B}_T = n\times\dim\mathrm{ker}(T)$?

Comment: It would be more precise to say that it is canonically isomorphic to it, but yes!

Comment: I've understood it. Thanks for your help!